# How to marked logs in output file

Tags: command-line

### That I have:

I have some commands in crontab, for example:

```
55 11 * * * curl -d '{"explorerId":'$(cat /root/id)', "turnOff":true}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/descriptions >> log/curl.log 2>&1
```

This command do something and saves result in file curl.log

### That to need:

I want, that to each note adds a string with information, like:

```
Date: 15.09.2018. 
Execute command: description
Result:

#...result of log from curl command
```

Comment: Please don't do it like this. Put it in a script and execute the script.

Comment: Fine). But in my case, I need to try this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
55 11 * * * { echo -e "date: $(date -I)\nExecute command: description\nResult:\n"; curl -d '{"explorerId":'$(cat /root/id)', "turnOff":true}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/descriptions ;} >> log/curl.log 2>&1
```

It will echo the date, discription and the result and append it in the log.

Comment: +1 but I personally would put the code in a script and then simply call the script from `cron` instead of further increasing the length of the current line and fiddle around with weird quoting problems just to get all the code into one line.